# Oracle SYSDATE-1 not returning 24 hour range

Tags: oracle

I have a table with a timestamp column. My query has a WHERE clause

```
            AND date_created.TIMESTAMP_DATA >=  (SYSDATE - 1)
```

This should return any timestamp which is now-24 hours but I do not get records done the previous day, only the day of (today). I checked that the db SYSDATE is accurate and manipulating date_created to today returns the results, however if date_create is yesterday @5pm, it does not return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a timezone issue. this solved it

```
AND date_created.TIMESTAMP_DATA >=  (SYSTIMESTAMP  AT TIME ZONE 'PST'- INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

Edited to include - INTERVAL '1' DAY instead of -1

Comment: When you work with `TIMESTAMPS` then you should better use `INTERVAL`, i.e. `>= SYSTIMESTAMP  AT TIME ZONE 'PST' - INTERVAL '1' DAY`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing query as:

```
AND date_created.TIMESTAMP_DATA >=  (SYSTIMESTAMP - 1)
```

Abhi

Comment: Ah although SYSDATE was accurate, SYSTIMESTAMP seems to be off. is SYSTIMESTAMP the servers date or the database date

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value in time zone of database server operation system time zone. Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get time of current user session time zone. Or `LOCALTIMESTAMP` to get a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone information) in time zone of current user session.